# What is the syntax to add a style to a date_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, syntax

I can't seem to figure this out.

I have this :

```
= date_select("card_signup", "dob", :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100, :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true)
```

And I want to include this `{:style => "width: 121px;"}`

But every way I try it fails. Anyone know the syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `date_select` method accepts four arguments, the last two of which (`options` and `html_options`) are Ruby hashes. Therefore you need to use braces to group the options corresponding to the third method argument so that the method can determine which passed options belong to which parameter.

Try this:

```
date_select("card_signup", "dob", { :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100,
  :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true },
  :style => "width: 121px;")
```

Comment: Curly braces ftw! You're too quick for me John :)

Comment: Thanks guys, you're all the best

Answer (score 2):

Given the docs at [rubyonrails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/), it appears the syntax would be something like:

`date_select("card_signup", "dob", { :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100, :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true}, {:style => "width: 121px;"})`

Since rails turns trailing arguments into hash for you, you can leave off the final braces:

`date_select("card_signup", "dob", { :end_year => DateTime.now.year - 100, :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true}, :style => "width: 121px;")`